# Where to place hash of attributes needed for several classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have two service objects which manage persistency:

```
class UpdateProductService
   <...>
  def update_product
    product_in_db.attributes = product_params
    product_in_db.save! if product_in_db.changed?
  end
   <...>
end
```

And the other one:

```
class CreateProductService
  <...>
  def create_product
    self.product = account.products.create!(product_params)
  end
  <...>
end
```

These objects both use the hash of attributes 'product_params' and some other hashes of attributes. Like this:

```
def product_params
  {
    archived: product.archived,
    available: product.available,
    category_id: product.category_id,
    short_description: product.short_description,
    description: product.description,
    title: product.title,
  }
end
```

These hashes are stored in both services now and duplicate each other. The question is: where can I place this and other hashes of attributes (in which file, where in the app-tree) to call them from my service objects with some 'product' as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a concern to me. Put this in `app/services/concerns` (or `app/service_objects/concerns`, whereever your services are).

```
module Concerns
  module WithProductParams
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def product_params
      {
        archived: product.archived,
        available: product.available,
        category_id: product.category_id,
        short_description: product.short_description,
        description: product.description,
        title: product.title,
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
class CreateProductService
  include Concerns::WithProductParams
```